# Multiple custom validator using same function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I implemented a generic logic client side and server side to use the same function in multiple custom validators. I'm currently testing it but it's only displaying the error message of the first control that fails and not the others. Can I pass the same function to multiple custom validators or do I need to create a separate function for each custom validator.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your code?  Meanwhile, check: 

The Display Property for all custom Validators is NOT set to none.
Manually call Page.Validate() before Page.IsValid()
NOTE: OnServerValidate will only run if there is a value in the WebControl (i.e. Text in a text box).  When I was making a test page, I ran into this problem.

Comment: you can use validation group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself, if you set the controlToValidate property of a custom validator you will get a weird behavior.